# Using libraries compiled for Windows on Linux

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linker, g++

I'm curious. I have a library (static and dynamic version) compiled with visual studio for Windows 64bit which I want to use on Linux. This is a commercial library and to get the same library compiled for Linux will take many days of emailing and reminding and so on and so on.

Can I use one of these two library variants (and these are not .net, but native libraries) to link to them on Linux machine?

Comment: I guess the tag is somewhat misleading ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you should be able to do so.

It would be an awful lot of work, but this is for instance how windows audio/video codecs are loaded by MPlayer.

You would have to write from scratch the interface wrapper, load the dll, and fix up the calling conventions.

It is a lot of work, however, that makes most sense if the library is self-contained, interfaces are scarce and well understood, and the other option would take too much time.

(essentially, if you understand what goes into writing a linker for both linux and windows) :)

Please let me know if you need any help with that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that, I'm afraid

Comment: Nah, it is not impossible, just hard and usually not worth the effort.

Comment: @gdot I didn't say "impossible". However, in general it IS impossible - the library may well make calls to Windows functions that Linux simply does not support.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that.
You can either try to get the linux version, or build your program on windows and run it on linux with emulator, for example wine.